# Chunking a story at specific indicators

Tags: python, nao-robot

For an assignment we have the following story:

```html
<g-beat head nod> Hello there kind person, I don't think I have met you before
<g-deictic hand point-body> I am NAO, although I look like a robot I have am very human-like!
<g-deictic hand point-forward> Just like you!
<g-deictic hand point-body> My Artificial Intelligence gives me the ability to be just like you, or maybe even better.
Who knows? <g-iconic hand mean2> I might take over the world one day, haha!
I am strong, <g-deictic head point-front> even if you drop me my legs won't break.
<g-beat hand emphasis> One day I will be the leader of the world and <g-iconic head mean1> <g-deictic hand point-forward> you can't stop me.
So I recommend you will be nice to me, or you will suffer in the future.
<g-beat head emphasis>Mwuahahahaha!"
```

My goal is to have a code recognize the annotations (`<x>`) and execute the movement while NAO says the sentence(s) which follow after it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alanimatedspeech.html#annotated-text) goes into a lot more detail, but here's an example to get you started. You can replace your annotations with special tags, `^start(animation name)` and `^wait(animation name)` that will be executed during the text to speech.

For example, if you wanted to put the animation `animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1` in your dialog, you could do the following.

```
^start(animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1) Hello there kind person, I don't think I have met you before
```

This will start the animation, and say the text *at the same time*. If you want to wait for the animation to finish before saying the text, you also use the wait tag like so:

```
^start(animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1)^wait(animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1) Hello there kind person, I don't think I have met you before
```

You can find the list of the animations available on NAO by default [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alanimationplayer-advanced.html#animationplayer-list-behaviors-nao).